# Iterate over Option instances until the first non-empty is found

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a number of functions that return `Option` values, like this

```
case class A()
case class B() 
case class C()

def optionA(): Option[A] = None
def optionB(): Option[B] = Some(B())
def optionC(): Option[C] = Some(C())
```

What I want to do is, I want to run these functions in sequence, but only until one of the functions returns an `Option` with a value (a `Some`). Then I want to have that value returned, without running the remaining functions.

This is my current implementation

```
val res:Option[Any] = Stream(
  () => optionA(),
  () => optionB(),
  () => optionC()
) .map(f => f())
  .filter(opt => opt.isDefined)
  .head
```

For the function implementations above, this applies `optionA` and `optionB`, gives me a `Some(B())`, and it never runs `optionC`, which is what I want.

But I'd like to know if there is is a better/simple/alternative implementation.

Something like `val findFirst = optionA compose optionB compose optionC`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
optionA().orElse(optionB()).orElse(optionC())
```

`orElse` will not evaluate its argument if `this` is defined.

Or if you have already the options in a collection/stream, you might do

```
options.find(_.isDefined).flatten
```

Comment: options.find(), seems access all elements.

Comment: It works if I have a list of lambdas, though: `List(()=>optionA(), ()=>optionB(),()=>optionC()).find(_().isDefined)`.

Comment: Thinking about it, the problem lies in contructing a Collection of Options without accessing the Options :) not in find()

Comment: why should find access all elements? (unless all are None of course)

Comment: Sorry, as I said, I was wrong about that. All my option-producing functions were called when constructing the collection, which led me to believe `find()` accessed all elements. The problem was that neither `List(a: A*)` nor `Stream(a: A*)` are lazy. If I construct a stream lazily, `find()` works fine: `cons(optionA(), cons(optionB(), cons(optionC(),Stream())))`

Comment: Ok, indeed, I had a lazyly constructed stream in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Say you now have a collection of `Option`s, you can then do this:

```
coll.foldLeft[Option[Int]](None)(_ orElse _)
```

Which will return you the first non-`None` value in the collection

Note that I explicitly mention the type of the collection, because scala can't infer what `orElse` should do without it... (`None` is of type `Option[Any]` by default)

If you have a giant list of options, it might be helpful to write

```
coll.view.foldLeft[Option[Int]](None)(_ orElse _)
```

Comment: Will not foldLeft traverse the collection to the end? (it would not in Haskell). Also <|> is orElse on scala options.

Comment: @DidierDupont yeah you were right, I changed it to `orElse` just before I saw your text, and yes it does indeed traverse to the end; but doing this has the benefit of using a collection of arbitrary length, ending on a Some

Comment: I just tried, foldLeft will access all elements (which means function executions in my case). I really want to stop once I hit the first `Some`

Comment: that is, of course, unless I use a list of lambdas `List(() => optionA(), () => optionB(),() =>optionC()).foldLeft[Option[Any]](None)(_ orElse _())`
`